# Mock Service Within Controller Returning Undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-controller

I am trying to test something pretty simple: a controller that calls a service that performs a http request.

Controller:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    'use strict';

    var MyController = function ($scope, MyService) {

        $scope.testScope = 'karma is working!';

        MyService.getData().then(function (data) {
            $scope.result = data.hour
        });
    };    

    module.exports = ['$scope', 'MyService', MyController ];
});
```

Test:

```
define(['require', 'angular-mocks'], function (require) {
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

describe("<- MyController Spec ->", function () {    

    var controller, scope, myService, serviceResponse;

    serviceResponse= {
        id: 12345,
        hour: '12'
    };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _MyService_, $q) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(serviceResponse);

        myService = _MyService_;
        spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        controller = _$controller_('MyController', {$scope: scope});  
        scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('should verify that the controller exists ', function() {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });    

    it('should have testScope scope equaling *karma is working*', function() {
        expect(scope.testScope ).toEqual('karma is working!');
    });
});
```

});

With the above, i get the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue')
```

Comment: I assume the lower-case version in the variable assignment in the 5th line of the method is a typo too then, yes?  Next step I'd take is to confirm what the 'undefined' is - spyOn, myService, or the return value of spyOn.  That may give you a clue as to what's missing.

Comment: Correct, is a typo in my question. Have updated.

Comment: How can i confirm what the undefined is?

Comment: What version of Jasmine are you using? That syntax is correct for version 2.0. For version 1x it would be andReturn.

Comment: @AndyHasIt - using version 1x

Answer (score 0):

Solved the question - was using Jasmine 1x.. Upgraded to 2.0 and works as expected